# How to prevent Doctrine from overriding column with generated value?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a database column called `modified` with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` definition.

When I modify and persist existing object the column stays with old value, because it is already set in the object property. Is there a way to tell Doctrine not to set that object property when persisting?

I got the desired result using `unset` before persisting, but this will make the code messy as not all entities have that property.

```
unset($object->modified);
$entityManager->persist($object);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding a `LifecycleEvent`.

In my `ClassMetadataBuilder` I have a method for creating the field:

```
public function addModifiedTimeField(): void {
    $this->createField("modified", "timestamp")->build();
    $this->addLifecycleEvent("unsetModified", "preFlush");
}
```

And entities that require `modified` field extend a `Versionable` class that defines the method.

```
abstract class Versionable extends JsonEncodable {

    protected $modified;

    public function getModified() {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    public function unsetModified(): void {
        $this->modified = null;
    }

}
```